# Unable to connect Jenkins master VM (Linux) from a windows slave VM through agent.jar

Tags: jenkins

Command ran to connect :

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://vmnx-testvm01.eur.ad.sag:8080/computer/vmdkp01%2Eeur%2Ead%2Esag/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 34c82af1e3a3d611fbdf56caassa5c511a97d696b1c134de91f1afassaasd4421b1e0dd4ca -workDir "C:\jenkins_slave"
```

Getting this error.

```
Apr 27, 2023 3:42:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: http://vmnx-testvm01.eur.ad.sag:8080/ provided port:50000 is not reachable
java.io.IOException: http://vmnx-testvm01.eur.ad.sag:8080/ provided port:50000 is not reachable
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:311)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:689)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:514)
```